# AngularJS+Phonegap wait for deviceReady() event fired in controller

Tags: android, html, angularjs, cordova

I am working on a mobile app(Ionic, Angular, Phonegap) but have problem with Phonegap+AngularJS.

I have this in my `index.html` :

```
<body ng-app="myApplication" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>
</body>
```

So I have a template named `home.html` which contains header, footer and a content that is also handled with `<ion-nav-view>` and varies with template. This content in `home/something.html` has an individual controller, `somethingCtrl`, for example.

Problem:
I put `document.addEventListener` in my `MainCtrl` that is main for all views. And as I know i can use Phonegap API only after the deviceReady is fired.

My MainCtrl code:

```
.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope, $window, $rootScope, $location) {
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

    alert('mainCtrl is loaded');

    function onOnline(){
                $rootScope.online = true;
            }
    function onOffline(){
                $rootScope.online = false;
            }

    function onDeviceReady() {
        alert('device is ready');
        document.addEventListener("online", onOnline, false);
        document.addEventListener("offline", onOffline, false);
        getLocalBooksStorageUrl();
        }
    function getLocalBooksStorageUrl(){
            window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, fileSystemSuccess,               null);
            function fileSystemSuccess(fileSystem) {
                var fp = fileSystem.root.toURL() + "/myApp"; // Returns Fulpath of local directory with my files
                $rootScope.localStorage = fp;
            }
        }
})
```

Code of my controller in which I want to access `$rootScope.localStorage` (view connected to this controller is FIRST in my app):

```
.controller('MybooksCtrl', function ($scope, $rootScope) {
    alert('myBooks is loaded');
    console.log($rootScope.localStorage); // undefined
})
```

So I have:

```
 alert -   mainCtrl is loaded
 alert -  myBooks is loaded
 console.log -  undefined ($rootScope.localStorage)
 alert - device is ready
```

What should I do or implement to force code of second controller to run only after device is ready?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `$apply` to execute code outside the angular context which then triggers a digest cycle to update the views.  After the `onDeviceReady()` function is called, set a scope variable 'deviceReady' to true.

```
.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope, $window, $rootScope, $location) {
    $scope.deviceReady = false;
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

    alert('mainCtrl is loaded');

    function onOnline(){
                $rootScope.online = true;
            }
    function onOffline(){
                $rootScope.online = false;
            }

    function onDeviceReady() {
       $scope.$apply(function() {
            alert('device is ready');
            document.addEventListener("online", onOnline, false);
            document.addEventListener("offline", onOffline, false);
            getLocalBooksStorageUrl();
            $scope.deviceReady = true;
        });
    }
    function getLocalBooksStorageUrl(){
            window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, fileSystemSuccess,               null);
            function fileSystemSuccess(fileSystem) {
                var fp = fileSystem.root.toURL() + "/myApp"; // Returns Fulpath of local directory with my files
                $rootScope.localStorage = fp;
            }
        }
})
```

Then in your 'MybooksCtrl', $watch for changes to deviceReady:

```
.controller('MybooksCtrl', function ($scope, $rootScope) {
    $scope.$watch('deviceReady', function(newVal) {
        if (newVal) {
            alert('myBooks is loaded');
            console.log($rootScope.localStorage); // no longer undefined
        }
    });
})
```